# Updating fields in one table that are not empty

Tags: drupal, mysql

I got this SQL:

```
UPDATE users2 
SET picture = 'sites/site2/files/pictures/' + picture;
WHERE picture NOT IS NULL
```

And the only thing I get are that all `picture` fields get the value `'0'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because adding does not work for strings. Use CONCAT() instead:

```
UPDATE users2 
SET picture = CONCAT('sites/site2/files/pictures/', picture)
WHERE pictures NOT IS NULL
```

Also, notice you have a semi-colon in the middle of the query... remove it or you'll get all rows updated!

Comment: yes thank you! and that `;` was a nice catch. It still isn't working because it doesn't like `NOT IS NULL`...ideas?

Comment: @WmasterJ: NOT IS NULL -> IS NOT NULL

Comment: Thank you Mark. Had just changed it to `!= ''`. But I believe both would have worked.

Answer (score 2):

In MySQL [`+`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/arithmetic-functions.html#operator_plus) means numerical addition. Your strings are being cast to integers, added, and then the result converted back to a string.

Use [CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) for string concatenation. Here's a fixed version of your query:

```
UPDATE users2 
SET picture = CONCAT('sites/site2/files/pictures/', picture)
WHERE picture IS NOT NULL
```